# Submitting form in a chrome extension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that consists on a form that when submitted executes `onsubmit="submit(); return false;"`.

I know the method submit works because I created a button outside the form with `onclick="submit()"` and that works perfectly.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" name="gaffeForm" onsubmit="submit(this); return false;">
    <div>
        <div class="submitField">
            <p class="formp">Title :</p>
            <input type="text" name="title" size="50" id="pageTitle" placeholder="Title" required />
        </div>
        <div class="submitField">
            <p class="formp">URL :</p>
            <input type="url" name="url" size="50" id="pageURL" placeholder="URL" required />
        </div>
        <div class="submitField">
            <p class="formp">Error :</p>
            <textarea name="gaffe" rows="5" cols="50" id="pageGaffe" placeholder="Gaffe" required ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="submitField">
            <p class="formp">Comment :</p>
            <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="50" id="gaffeComment" placeholder="Your comment on the gaffe" required ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="submitField">
            <p class="formp">Tags :</p>
            <input type="text" name="tags" size="50" id="gaffeTags" placeholder="Separate the tags with a comma" required />
        </div>
        <div id="GaffeSubmit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the `submit()` function:

```
function submit(f) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var title = $('#pageTitle').val().replace(/\//g, "%2F");
    var url = $('#pageURL').val().replace(/http:\/\//, "").replace(/https:\/\//, "").replace(/\//g, "%2F");
    var gaffe = $('#pageGaffe').val().replace(/\//g, "%2F");
    var comment = $('#gaffeComment').val().replace(/\//g, "%2F");
    var tags = $('#gaffeTags').val().replace(/\//g, "%2F");

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/F0ETF87dar8F7deO92K/" + title + "/" + url + "/" + gaffe + "/" + comment + "/" + tags, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) window.close();
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.send();
    return false;
}
```

So, when I click submit with all my fields filled in what happens is that the fields comment and tags go blank, and that's it... I've tried a lot of different ways of executing `submit()` but none have worked... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page loaded from the extension or is it loaded from a website and you are trying to have the `submit()` function in an extension content script called?

If the `submit` function is in a content script it can't be called from a website as the chrome extension security system doesn't allow javascript calls between page content and javascript in content scripts.

Comment: The form is in popup.html and submit is a function inside popup.html too.

Comment: Ah. Do you load the content script explicitly inside popup.html? I'm not sure if the content scripts are all automatically available to your html file, or if you have to explicitly load them, and your source file fragment doesn't appear to load any explicit script files. If you copy your `submit` function into popup.html does it work then?

Comment: My content script doesn't have anything to do with this. My submit function IS inside popup.html

Answer (score 0):

Sending request to a different port is prohibited by the cross-origin policy. If you open error console you will probably see a security error.

You can set domain permissions in the manifest, but you cannot set port.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ports... The XMLHttpRequest works fine because the function submit works flawlessly when executed by a button outside the form, but it doesn't execute when I press submit. And I've tried deleting everything that's in the function and just putting an alert and it still doesn't execute

Comment: @Alberto Elias: I mean you are trying to submit to port 3000. Unless you are currently viewing this page at port 3000 it wouldn't allow you to make XMLHttpRequest to 3000 from 80.

Comment: well, it does work! And it's in port 3000 because my server right now is in localhost so the web is in that port. But I know the method works because I've executed it by pressing a different button outside the from different from submit.